# Don't import implementation files from another package when import a public class in flutter

Tags: flutter

When I import a public class in Flutter like this:

```
import 'package:wheel/src/log/app_log_handler.dart';
```

shows the waring:

```
Don't import implementation files from another package.
```

this is the waring detail:

[image]

why give this tips? what is the best way to handle it? I really want the log handler to public because I want all of my project use the same log handler, I do not want put the log handler to every project every time by the copy paste way.By the way, I import package like this:

```
 wheel:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/wheel.git
      ref: main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TLDR
> The package should have a file that only shows the selected files such as  `'package:wheel/wheel.dart``

You should not import the `'package:wheel/src/log/app_log_handler.dart';`directly.

Instead import 'package:wheel/wheel.dart`;
This import will export all required public types needed to work with the  library.

Normally this files content will be just exports like [this](https://github.com/rlazom/easy_dynamic_theme/blob/master/lib/easy_dynamic_theme.dart)

```
export 'package:wheel/src/log/app_log_handler.dart';
export 'package:wheel/src/widgets/wheel_btn.dart';
export 'package:wheel/src/widgets/wheel_switch_two.dart';
export 'package:wheel/src/widgets/wheel_switch.dart';
```

See also the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-libraries) on this.